Variables de documento docx
Estoy tratando de obtener las variables de una plantilla docx, pero me da este error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
PhpOffice\PhpWord\Metadata\DocInfo::getDocVars() in
C:\xampp\htdocs\Formulario\upload.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\Formulario\upload.php on line 21.

Este es mi código:
<?php
require './vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;

$directorio = 'plantillasWord/';
$archivo = $directorio . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $archivo)) {
    echo '<script>alert("El archivo se subio correctamente")</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("Error en la subida del archivo")</script>';
}

if ($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
} else {
    $uploadedFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    
    // Lee el archivo de Word
    $phpWord = IOFactory::load($archivo);
    
    // Obtiene todas las variables del documento
    $variables = $phpWord->getDocInfo()->getDocVars();
    
    // Muestra las variables
    echo '<h2>Variables del Documento</h2>';
    if (count($variables) > 0) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($variables as $name => $value) {
            echo "<li><strong>$name:</strong> $value</li>";
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>No se encontraron variables en el documento.</p>';
    }
}
?>

A alguien más le ha pasado alguna vez?
Un saludo

Hola Ivan. Al parecer, tu archivo .docx es una plantilla, por lo que deberías utilizar TemplateProcessor y el método getVariables()

El mensaje dice que estas haciendo un llamado a un método que no existe en esa clase.
Intenta leer las variables con
$variables = $phpWord->getVariables();

Luego para mostrar las variables usa :
foreach ($variables as $variable) {
    echo "<li><strong>{$variable->getName()}:</strong> {$variable->getValue()}</li>";
}


El tipo DocInfo definitivamente no contiene nada que ver con variables.
